# Kubernetes networking policy for service restriction

Tags: kubernetes

I have many namespaces and multiple services running on each namespace.

We are using calico plugin in our Kubernetes ckuster. I am looking for a way to restrict access b/w services/ingress.

Say, Service A, Service B and Service C are running in Namespace A.

I want Service B to access Service A, but not Service C. Can this be done with Networking policy in Kubernetes? Is an example available?

Also, I want no services from Namespace B accessing any services in Namespace A. But, I need some services from Namespace C accessing some services in namespace A.  Can this be done using calico?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is entirely possible.

Kubernetes network policies support both ingress/egress rules. Also there are three types of traffic selectors:

- Based on ipBlock
- Based on namespace selector
- Based on pod selector

You can create labels on your pods and used those label selectors for identifying the pods to apply the policies.

Here is the [link](https://v1-9.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.9/#networkpolicy-v1beta1-extensions) for the K8S api documentation for network policies.

And this [github](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes) repository has lot of examples.